# How to pass arguments to GWT compiler using Maven GWT plugin?

Tags: java, gwt, maven

I need to pass "-deploy src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deploy/" argument to GWT Compiler in gwt-maven-plugin configuration.

My purpose is to integrate remote logger using gwt-log.

To achieve I need to pass above mentioned argument to GWT compiler.

Thanks!!
Bhavesh

Comment: What version of the plugin are you using?

Comment: I am using gwt-maven-plugin of version 2.2.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [gwt-maven-plugin](https://gwt-maven-plugin.github.io/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/compile.html)

```
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    <plugins>
      [...]
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <configuration>
              <deploy>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/deploy/</deploy>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      [...]
    </plugins>
  </build>
  [...]
</project>
```

As noted you'll need to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this parameter is only available since 2.3.0-1 version of `gwt-maven-plugin` (see [here](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html)).

Comment: Updating to 2.3.0-1 (or latest 2.4.0) is possible - they are backward compatible, but you do need to set a dependency in the plugin of what GWT vers you want to use. Unless you are depending on specific bugs/behavior of the old plugin, I can think of no reason to not update. http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/user-guide/using-different-gwt-sdk-version.html

Comment: I updated gwt-maven-plugin to latest and it worked. In addition, by default it created symbolMaps in the directory where I want them to be in so I don't need to provide any additional configuration, mere version change is enough.